Minhag not to have the moon shine on a sleeping person?
I saw in a Holocaust memoir a claim by the author that in Poland there was an accepted minhag not to have the moon shine directly on a sleeping person. He mentioned it in the context of someone  who was known as a  Talmid Chochom doing something to avoid it (he said who the person was).
I know plenty of people who were born in the same part of Poland and  who had the  same  general hashkafa and minhagim as this author  but I never  heard or saw anyone else mention such a thing.
The Mogen Avraham does say not to look at the moon during Kiddush Levana after the first glance but the (non-Kabbalistic) explanations given for that Mogen Avrohom don’t apply to sleeping in its light.
There are  non-Jewish reasons given not to sleep in moon light (some believing that it impairs the quality of sleep, others just superstitions).
Is anyone familiar with such a minhag and or know why it exists, who started it etc.?

What book was this in? Who was the תלמיד חכם?

cf. orach chaim 664

The Gemara in Pesahim 111a brings down the following:

א"ר יצחק מאי דכתיב (תהלים כג, ד) גם כי אלך בגיא צלמות לא אירא רע כי
אתה עמדי זה הישן בצל דקל יחידי ובצל לבנה ובצל דקל יחידי לא אמרן אלא
דלא נפיל טולא דחבריה עילויה אבל נפל טולא דחבריה עילויה לית לן בה אלא
הא דתניא הישן בצל דקל יחידי בחצר והישן בצל לבנה דמו בראשו היכי דמי אי
לימא דלא נפל טולא דחבריה עילויה אפילו בשדה נמי אלא לאו שמע מינה בחצר
אף על גב דנפיל טולא דחבריה עילויה שמע מינה ובצילה של לבנה לא אמרן אלא
במערבה אבל במדינחתא לית לן בה
R. Isaac said: What is meant by the verse, Yea, though I walk through
the valley of the shadow of death, I will fear no evil, for Thou art
with me? This refers to him who sleeps in the shadow of a single
palm-tree or in the shadow of the moon. Now in respect to the shadow
of a single palm-tree this holds good only where the shadow of the
neighboring [tree] does not fall upon it; but if the shadow of the
neighboring tree falls upon it, it does not matter. Then when it was
taught: He who sleeps in the shadow of a single palm-tree in a
courtyard and he who sleeps in the shadow of the moon, has his
blood on is own head, how is it meant? Shall we say that the shadow
of the neighbouring tree does not fall upon it, — then even in a field
too [it is dangerous]? Hence you may surely infer from this that in a courtyard [there is danger] even if the shadow of the neighboring tree
fall on it. This proves it. And in respect to the shadow of the moon
too, this holds good only when [it falls] in the west, but when it is
in the east it does not matter.

The Ibn 'Ezra on Psalms 121:6 states:

הלבנה בלילה תוסיף לחה מולדת תחלואים וזה דבר ברור ומנוסה
The moon at night generates phlegm and breeds diseases and this is an
obvious and proven thing

R. Eliezer ha-Gadol (11th c. Germany) left the following instruction to his son (Orhoth Haim 63):

בני אל תשב בצל החמה בימי תמוז ואב וכל שכן שלא תישן בלילה לאור הלבנה
ועל זה נאמר יומם השמש לא יככה וירח בלילה ביום מפני מרירי ובלילה מפני
איגרת בת מחלת וכל שכן כשהלבנה בחידושה ה' ישמור את נפשך ה' ישמור צאתך
ובואך מעתה ועד עולם
My son, do not dwell in the shadow of the sun in the season of Tamuz
and Abh and all the more so certainly do not sleep at night in the
light of the moon, and on this it was said (Psalms 121:6) "The sun
shall not smite thee by day, nor the moon by night" by day because of
Meriri and by night because of Agerath bath-Mahalath, and all the more so when the moon is renewed may God guard over your life and may
He guard over you in your comings and goings now and forever.

The Ta'maei ha-Minhagim 464 cites the abovementioned view of R. Eliezer ha-Gadol.
Shulhan Arukh ha-Rabh (H. Shemirath ha-Nefesh 9):

ולא יישן בחצר בצל לבנה של כתל החצר, מפני שהשדים דרכם להלך בלילה, ובזמן
שהלבנה זורחת מתיראין לילך במקום האור והולכין במקום הצל. ואם הלבנה
במערב והוא ישן בצל הכתל במזרחו — אין לחש.
And not to sleep in a courtyard in the shadow of the moon of the wall
of the courtyard, since it is the manner of shedim to so go at night,
at times when the moon is shining they are afraid to go in the places
of light and go instead in the shadow. And if the moon is in the west
and he sleeps in the shade of the the wall to its east, there is no
concern.

The Rambam and Shulhan Arukh altogether omit any such concern. Nevertheless in light of the aforementioned sources, some more recent sources take up the issue.
The Shu"T Mishnath Yosef of R. Yosef Lieberman (11, 142) holds as follows:

הנה הרשב"ם בפסחים קיא א פי' בצלה של לבנה ההולך בלילה כשהלבנה זורחת
והוא הולך בצל הכתלים שדרך השדים להלוך בלילה ובזמן שהלבנה זורחת
מתייראין לילך במקום האור והולכין במקום הצל עכ"ל...וא"כ הסכנה היא רק אם
ישן בצל הלבנה דהיינו במקום שמוצל מאור הלבנה אבל באור הלבנה עצמה מותר
לישן
The Rashbam on Pesahim 111a explains that in the shadow of the moon,
one who goes at night while the moon shines and walks in the shadow of
the walls, in the manner of sheidim that at night are afraid to go
where the moon shines and so walk in the shade... and if that is so,
the danger is only if one sleeps in the shade of the moon, which is a
place protected from the light of the moon, however in the light of
the moon itself it is permitted to sleep.

R. Barukh Sheraga addressing the question of whether soldiers may sleep out in the field beneath the moonlight writes (Barukh Omer YD #34):

ומדברי הגמרא נראה שהסכנה היא רק בצל הלבנה אבל לאור הלבנה אין סכנה אולם
בצוואתו של רבי אליעזר הגדול כתוב שיש סכנה לישן לאור הלבנה ועל זה נאמר
תהלים קכא ו יומם השמש לא יככה וירח בלילה ב וגם בדרך הטבע יש בזה קצת
סכנה כמו שכתב האבן עזרא תהלים קכא ו שידוע כי השמש תזיק ברוב החום שלה
והלבנה בלילה תוסיף לחה מולדת תחלואים וזה הדבר ברור ומנוסה. ולמעשה
לכתחילה ראוי לחוש לזה ולישון כמקום מכוסה שהלמה אינה זורחת שם אולם
כמקום הצורך אפשר להקל כזה כשם שאנחנו מקילים כזוגות מפני שהשדים אינם
מצויים כינינו ג וגם הסכנה שכתב האכן עזרא כיום לא ידוע שיש כזה סכנה
ויתכן שנשתנו הטכעים
From the words of the Gemara it seems that the danger is only in the
shadow of the moon but that in the light of the moon there is no
danger, however in the will of R. Eli'ezer ha-Gadol it is written that
there is a danger to sleep in the light of the moon and it is that
which is referred to in "The sun shall not smite thee by day, nor the moon by night" , and similarly within the
naturalistic view there is some danger as the Ibn 'Ezra attests on
Psalms 121:6 that it is known that the sun damages through the
intensity of its heat and that the moon increases phlegm and brings
disease and that such is clear and obvious. In practice, ab initio, it
is proper to be concerned with this and to sleep in a place that is
covered and where the moon doesn't shine, however in a place of need
it is possible to be lenient in this in the same manner as we are
lenient regarding zugoth since the sheidim are not found among us and
because the danger that the Ibn 'Ezra attests to is not known to us
today and perhaps nature changed.

So in short, it would be unsurprising to find certain pious minded individuals concerned for the abovementioned views avoiding sleeping in the moonlight.

God told us to sleep in the shadow of the moon for at least 7 days a year. (Well, mostly shadow of the moon. More shadow than not.)

@DoubleAA agreed... if I find a source that addresses that I'll update.
